# Using the lowest's node data by type

Tags: javascript, mysql, algorithm

I'll demonstrate my data in a javascript array. I'm looking for a solution either in JS or Mysql. The database table is flat just like this array.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": null,
    "color_id": null,
    "style": "new-age",
    "amount": "30.00"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": 1,
    "color_id": null,
    "style": "new-age",
    "amount": "5.00"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": 1,
    "color_id": 1,
    "style": "new-age",
    "amount": "6.00"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": 1,
    "color_id": null,
    "style": "old-school",
    "amount": "25.00"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": null,
    "color_id": null,
    "style": "old-school",
    "amount": "2.00"
}]
```

I'm specifically looking at these columns:

- account_id
- size
- color

I want the results to be grouped by style so for example if you a user specifies a size and a color I want the result to look like this:

```
[{
    "id": 3,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": 1,
    "color_id": 1,
    "style": "new-age",
    "amount": "6.00"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": 1,
    "color_id": null,
    "style": "old-school",
    "amount": "25.00"
}]
```

Another scenario lets say they don't specify size or color_id the result would look like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": null,
    "color_id": null,
    "style": "new-age",
    "amount": "30.00"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "account_id": 1,
    "size_id": null,
    "color_id": null,
    "style": "old-school",
    "amount": "2.00"
}];
```

The assumption is there will alway be a record for account_id.

- If a color_id is specified use that record above all else.
- If a size_id is specified use that record only above account id.
- Default to account_id for pricing if neither color_id or size_id are specified.

Comment: please, can you explain the result of `a user specifies a size and a color`, because the color is either `null` or `1`?

Answer (score 0):

This proposal features a small function `select(from, where, sort)` with three parameters.

- **from**: The data source as array, required.
- **where**: An object with one ore more key/value pairs, if more than one is supplied, the conditions are with **and** chained. The parameter is ommitted if falsy.
- **sort**: An array with key/value pair objects which sortes the result set with the key ascending with value 1, descending with value -1. The sort features a string sort. The parameter is ommitted if falsy.

The test case returns:

1. All sets with color_id = 1, sorted by style ascending.
2. All sets with size_id = 1, sorted by style ascending.
3. All sets with color_id = null and size_id = null, sorted by style ascending.
4. All sets sorted by style ascending and amount ascending.

```js
var data = [
        { "id": 1, "account_id": 1, "size_id": null, "color_id": null, "style": "new-age", "amount": "30.00" },
        { "id": 2, "account_id": 1, "size_id": 1, "color_id": null, "style": "new-age", "amount": "5.00" },
        { "id": 3, "account_id": 1, "size_id": 1, "color_id": 1, "style": "new-age", "amount": "6.00" },
        { "id": 3, "account_id": 1, "size_id": 1, "color_id": null, "style": "old-school", "amount": "25.00" },
        { "id": 3, "account_id": 1, "size_id": null, "color_id": null, "style": "old-school", "amount": "2.00" }
    ];

function select(from, where, sort) {
    var data = from.slice(0);
    where && Object.keys(where).forEach(function (k) {
        data = data.filter(function (d) {
            return d[k] === where[k];
        });
    });
    sort && data.sort(function (a, b) {
        var value = 0;
        sort.some(function (el) {
            var key = Object.keys(el)[0];
            value = ~el[key] ? a[key].localeCompare(b[key]) : b[key].localeCompare(a[key]);
            return value;
        });
        return value;
    });
    return data;
}

function print(o) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(o, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
}

print(select(data, { color_id: 1 }, [{ style: 1 }]));
print(select(data, { size_id: 1 }, [{ style: 1 }]));
print(select(data, { color_id: null, size_id: null }, [{ style: 1 }]));
print(select(data, undefined, [{ style: 1 }, { amount: 1 }]));
```